# How can I make the TextArea in Java black?

Tags: java, textarea

I want to make my `TextArea` *black* instead of *white*. I wish to make the `Window` fullscreen where the whole screen would be the `TextArea` that's *black* and would have *white* letters.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For swing components

```
JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
//Set background black
txt.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
//Set Foreground(text) white
txt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
```

Same goes for the awt components

```
TextArea txt = new TextArea();
//Set background black
txt.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
//Set Foreground(text) white
txt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
```

The `setForeground` and `setBackground` methods belong to the `JComponent`/`Component` class and hence accessible to every component, as all the Swing/AWT component, at some place up the hierarchy, will extend these classes.

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
txt.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
txt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
```